# <dt> content longer than <dd> content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap’s `dl-horizontal` to make the `dt` and `dd` content appear on the same line I have the following problem since my `dt` content is in some cases longer than my `dd` content. And the width of the `dt` is limited.

```css
dt {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Very long dt content (like really long):</dt>
    <dd>
      short
    </dd>
    <dt>Very long dt content (like really long):</dt>
    <dd>
      short
    </dd>
</dl>
```

This renders to something like this:

[image: Rendering of the HTML/CSS]

So the second `dd` content show up in the wrong line.

Comment: Really, the term is longer than the actual definition? Doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some syntax errors in your code above, with extraneous closing `</dt>`s appearing. Essentially you just need to play around with the width of the `<dt>`

Corrrected syntax:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Very long dt content (like really long):</dt>
  <dd>short</dd>
  <dt>Very long dt content (like really long):</dt>
  <dd>short</dd>
</dl>
```

and the CSS:

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Kh4/2/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mntion that the width of the dt is limited (eg 160 px).

Comment: The additional </dt> were just typos in the question.